# Summing totals from multiple tables in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

Folks. I can't seem to find an answer for this issue. I can do it in SQL Server, but I'm working with Access 2013 now and my usual SQL tricks don't seem to work.

I need to create a class cost v. revenue summary report.

I have three tables: class list, cost list, registration list. The costs and registrations (costs & revenue) are both tied to the class list by a key field identifying that class across all tables.

I am able to run a cost report or a revenue report and the totals for each class are fine, but when I combine them to get the net for each class, the costs are multiplied by the number of lines in the registration report and vice versa.

I've tried using Outer Join but access doesn't like it, even with the [] in the right place. It would be better to keep this in access as moving away from excel is the whole point.

[tables and expected results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1pRlI.jpg)

[incorrect results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wm3I4.jpg)

Here's the SQL behind the bad results. I know these joins are wrong, but I can't get access to accept any other kind of join.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Classes.ID,
       Classes.Title,
       Classes.Instructor,
       Classes.Date,
       Sum(Costs.Amount) AS [Sum Of Amount],
       Sum(Registrations.Tuition) AS [Sum Of Tuition],
       Count(*) AS [Count Of Classes]
FROM (Classes
      LEFT JOIN Registrations ON Classes.[ID] = Registrations.[Class ID])
LEFT JOIN Costs ON Classes.[ID] = Costs.[Class ID]
GROUP BY Classes.ID,
         Classes.Title,
         Classes.Instructor,
         Classes.Date;
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Build an aggregate query for costs and an aggregate query for revenue then join the 2 aggregate queries to class list table.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  First of all, see [LEFT and RIGHT JOIN Operations](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/LEFT-JOIN-RIGHT-JOIN-Operations-ebb18b36-7976-4c6e-9ea1-c701e9f7f5fb).  The SQL syntax, including JOIN keywords, are not identical to SQL Server.

Comment: You mention "SQL tricks", "any other kind of join" and the ability to "do it in SQL Server". If you have tried such things, or if you think that other syntax works elsewhere, it can be worth including such examples rather than only mentioning them.  Not only can that provide something to work with, but can reveal details that might not come across in words. I don't see how any join or syntax would let you do a single query to get aggregates over different tables.  Even if they are subqueries, you need to sum up the costs and the tuitions separately.

Answer (score 1):

You need two separate queries to sum up values for distinct tables, even though they are joined to the same primary table.  Otherwise the select portion of the SQL will perform a cross join on the two other tables, effectively re-selecting each cost value for every registration.  This selection process occurs before grouping and aggregation (i.e. sum, count).  That's why you get the multiplied sums.

DISTINCTROW is ineffective since the query is selecting values based on fields from *every table* in the join, so it must effectively keep every row from the original set.  DISTINCTROW does *not* first select rows from one table then independently select rows from another table (nor does it sum them up separately).  Instead, the full selection and cross join are applied, then it filters out rows by asking "Does this row only contain data from already selected source tables rows?"  If the answer is yes then it excludes that from the final selection.  But if the selected data contains values from every table in the join, then each row is already unique and so nothing will be excluded.

Define one sum:

```
SELECT Classes.ID As ID,
       Sum(Costs.Amount) AS [Sum Of Amount]
FROM Classes
     LEFT JOIN Costs 
     ON Classes.[ID] = Costs.[Class ID]
GROUP BY Classes.ID
```

Then the other:

```
SELECT Classes.ID As ID,
       Sum(Registrations.Tuition) AS [Sum Of Tuition]
FROM Classes
     LEFT JOIN Registrations ON Classes.[ID] = Registrations.[Class ID]
GROUP BY Classes.ID
```

You could save these queries in Access and then refer to them in other queries by name, or you can include embedded SQL.  In this case it's just personal preference, but embedded queries cannot be inspected or edited with the visual Design View, rather must be edited with SQL view from within Access.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW Classes.ID, Classes.Title,
       Classes.Instructor, Classes.Date,
       CostsAgg.[Sum Of Amount],
       RegAggs.[Sum Of Tuition]
FROM (Classes LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT Classes.ID As ID, Sum(Costs.Amount) AS [Sum Of Amount]
       FROM Classes LEFT JOIN Costs ON Classes.[ID] = Costs.[Class ID]
       GROUP BY Classes.ID) AS CostsAgg ON Classes.ID = CostsAgg.ID)
      LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT Classes.ID As ID, Sum(Registrations.Tuition) AS [Sum Of Tuition]
         FROM Classes LEFT JOIN Registrations ON Classes.[ID] = Registrations.[Class ID]
         GROUP BY Classes.ID) AS RegAggs
      ON Classes.ID = RegAggs.ID
GROUP BY Classes.ID,
         Classes.Title,
         Classes.Instructor,
         Classes.Date;
```

I did not include a Count column, because it was unclear from the example what you are really trying to count.  You can of course separately include a Count field in any of the sub/queries or all of them to get different values.

Comment: C Perkins, this worked. Frankly these aggregate queries are right on the edge of my query skills. I was able to convert the code to the specifics of my database and run a report that compares the two totals accurately. I'll be studying this closely for a while to come. Thank you.