# MS-Access: Calculate Stock From 3 Tables

Tags: sql, ms-access

I was reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45202937/summing-totals-from-multiple-tables-in-ms-access) from `StackOverFlow` to adjust query to calculate stock from 3 tables. I have 3 tables `tblItems`, `tblPurchase` and `tblSales`. `tblItems` contains items information like below.

```
ItemCode    Description                 ItemClass   ItemCategory        ReorderLevel    Unit    Stop
IT000001    Tonner 226A                 Tonner      IT Accessories      10              Pc(s)   No
IT000002    Keyborad (A4Tech, Slim Key) Keyboard    IT Accessories      10              Pc(s)   No
IT000003    Mouse (Wireless)            Mouse       IT Accessories      10              Pc(s)   No
SI000001    A4 Size Paper               Paper       Office Stationary   10              Pc(s)   No
SI000002    Pen (Black)                 Pen         Office Stationary   10              Pc(s)   No
SI000003    Pen (Blue)                  Pen         Office Stationary   10              Pc(s)   No
```

Screenshots of my tables

***tblItems:***

[image]

***tblPurchase:***

[image]

***tblSales:***

[image]

And my expected result like below

[image]

In query result items details will come from `tblItems`. Sum purchase quantity per item and sum sales quantity per item then minus `SalesQuantity` from `PurchaseQuantity` to see stock.

Here is my query which gives me following warning.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW tblItems.ItemCode, TblItems.Description, TblItems.ItemClass, TblItems.ItemCategory, TblPurchaseAgg.[pQuantity], TblSalesAggs.[sQuantity]
FROM (TblItems 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT TblItems.ItemCode AS ItemCode, Sum(TblPurchase.Quantity) AS pQuantity FROM TblItems LEFT JOIN TblPurchase ON TblItems.ItemCode = TblPurchase.ItemCode GROUP BY TblItems.ItemCode)  
AS TblPurchaseAgg ON TblItems.ItemCode = TblPurchaseAgg.ItemCode) 

LEFT JOIN 

(SELECT TblItems.ItemCode AS ItemCode, Sum(tblSales.Quantity) AS sQuantity FROM TblItems LEFT JOIN tblSales ON TblItems.ItemCode = tblSales.ItemCode GROUP BY TblItems.ItemCode)  AS TblSalesAggs ON TblItems.ItemCode = TblSalesAggs.ItemCode

GROUP BY TblItems.ItemCode, TblItems.Description, TblItems.ItemClass, TblItems.ItemCategory;
```

[image]

Seeking help to resolve the warning and get my expected output. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the outer/first group. Since your item table will `[probably]` will never have duplicate items the records returned will always be unique.

the both left joins you are using is grouping by `itemCode` so they also will only return one record per item. so grouping overall is not required.

this could work for you:

```
    SELECT 
    tblItems.ItemCode, 
    TblItems.Description, 
    TblItems.ItemClass, 
    TblItems.ItemCategory, 
    TblPurchaseAgg.pQuantity, 
    TblSalesAggs.sQuantity,
    (TblPurchaseAgg.pQuantity - TblSalesAggs.sQuantity) as stock,
    TblItems.unit
FROM 
    (TblItems 
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 
                TblPurchase.ItemCode AS ItemCode, 
                Sum(TblPurchase.Quantity) AS pQuantity 
            FROM
                TblPurchase
            GROUP BY TblPurchase.ItemCode
        )  AS TblPurchaseAgg
    ON TblItems.ItemCode = TblPurchaseAgg.ItemCode) 
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            tblSales.ItemCode AS ItemCode, 
            Sum(tblSales.Quantity) AS sQuantity 
        FROM 
            tblSales
        GROUP BY tblSales.ItemCode
    )  AS TblSalesAggs 
    ON TblItems.ItemCode = TblSalesAggs.ItemCode
```

Comment: I was thinking exactly like you but couldn't figure it out. You missed a comma (,) here `TblSalesAggs.sQuantity (TblPurchaseAgg.pQuantity - TblSalesAggs.sQuantity) as stock`. I have managed it. Finally it worked for. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1):

Could you pls use this -

```
SELECT 
tblItems.ItemCode, TblItems.Description, TblItems.ItemClass, TblItems.ItemCategory, TblPurchaseAgg.[pQuantity], TblSalesAggs.[sQuantity]
FROM TblItems 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT TblPurchase.ItemCode AS ItemCode, Sum(TblPurchase.Quantity) AS pQuantity FROM TblPurchase GROUP BY TblPurchase.ItemCode)  TblPurchaseAgg ON TblItems.ItemCode = TblPurchaseAgg.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN (SELECT tblSales.ItemCode AS ItemCode, Sum(tblSales.Quantity) AS sQuantity FROM tblSales GROUP BY tblSales.ItemCode) TblSalesAggs ON TblItems.ItemCode = TblSalesAggs.ItemCode

GROUP BY TblItems.ItemCode, TblItems.Description, TblItems.ItemClass, TblItems.ItemCategory;
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I have tried your answer but it gives me `Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'TblItems.ItemCode=TblPurchaseAgg.ItemCode Left Join ....` warning message. I was trying to troubleshoot the query but no luck. Can you please check again?

Comment: I updated the SQL. i removed all comments. Could you pls try again?

Comment: I tried by removing comments already but same warning. I also tried your edited codes but same warnings. [Can you please check file from this google drive link.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LkaeiGnGZ1yMw2nY5hfUlL3fSR_UfFQy/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: The issue was with sql structure and DISTINCT. When you use group by you shouldn't use distinct, its auto distinct. Anyways, spend like few minutes on the SQL. Latest SQL is working in my GoogleDrive.

Comment: My bad luck. Still same warning here. Can you please give me the link to download file that is working.

Comment: i am not sure how come its giving same error. can you pls send me full SQL and full error you are facing. I can send you the mdb later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219947/discussion-between-harun24hr-and-koushik-roy).